# Facing issues while e-filing provisional patent application

Tags: filing

I am trying to file utility patent - provisional application.
Facing these kind of issues?

[image: At the time of submitting it - got these issues]
How to deal with it? I prepared all my documents using MS Word or MS Visio - then just saved them as PDF file. Is that an issue? 
My file are in landscape mode NOT portrait. Is that a problem?

Comment: Seemingly the errors relates to the fonts not being embedded in the PDF. So perhaps regenerate the PDFs with the fonts embedded? Which I think, in Word, is covered by an option in the options for generating a PDF about "ISO compliant". But the operations of Word and Visio are well beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Maca's comment is correct. The solution depends on the platform you are using (I assume Windows). Try Googling "PDF embedded fonts".

Comment: @Maca. thanks this works. But I am still getting this warning(not error): The page size in the PDF is too large. The pages should be 8.5 x 11 or A4. If this PDF is submitted, the pages will be resized upon entry into the Image File Wrapper and may affect subsequent processing.

Comment: @EricShain. thanks. But for SB/16 and SB/15A - i am still getting this error:The attached PDF file references a non-embedded font: CIDFont+F1. Please remove file, embed the font and reattach.

Comment: Tricky. In Word, I'd try selecting all and then picking a common font like "Times" or "Ariel". Somewhere in the document (perhaps in the Visio figures) is an odd font.

Comment: Thanks everybody - I am able to file the provisional patent.  Word setting is easy to find out. For SB/16 and SB/15A- i used PDF Architect 4 rather than Adobe Acrobat. Able to get thru. There were warnings but i reached out to the toll free # and they said - you can ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word(MS Office 2010)-you can make it save the PDF following these steps. Try to save the MS Word document as PDF and check the ISO* checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't make sense of all the instructions I've found or they just don't work for me.

I found a workaround that actually works!

Just screengrab (I used my iPad) each page of your PDF (or any type of document, actually), and then use Acrobat or PDF Filler or any app that will merge photos into a PDF document.

Seems wonky but actually works! No font errors!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Although this avoids font errors, it creates bitmap images of each page which are of low resolution and much larger in file size. Really this is a very bad way of avoiding the font issue.